# Adding some parts in a TextBox vb

Tags: vb.net

I was wondering if there is a way to allow only some sections of a textbox to be editable in a frozen sentence.
e.g:

```
He share of ________ to worse. Weddings and any opinions suitable smallest nay. 
My he houses or months settle remove ladies appear. Engrossed suffering 
supposing he recommend do eagerness.
```

where the underscore can be edited but the sentences cannot be changed at all.

Thanks

Comment: No, there is not. Use a label before and a label after, and use a TextBox for the part you want to allow to be edited.

Comment: I've never tried such a thing but it might be possible with a `MaskedTextBox`. I'm not sure that they can be multiline though. I would probably just use a `TextBox` for the editable part and then display the rest of the text in a `Label` or perhaps by drawing in on the form using GDI+. That's probably more manageable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution for your example
[image]

```
Public Class Form1

Private SelectionStart As Integer = 10
Private SelectionEnd As Integer = 20
Private SelectionCurrent As Integer = 10

Private Sub CursorControl(Optional ByVal e As Object = Nothing)
    If SelectionCurrent > SelectionEnd Then
        SelectionCurrent = SelectionEnd
    ElseIf SelectionCurrent < SelectionStart Then
        SelectionCurrent = SelectionStart
    End If
    If TextBox1.SelectionStart >= SelectionEnd Then
        If Not e Is Nothing Then
            e.Handled = True
            e = Nothing
        End If
        TextBox1.SelectionStart = SelectionEnd
        TextBox1.SelectionLength = 0
        Me.SelectionCurrent = TextBox1.SelectionStart
    ElseIf TextBox1.SelectionStart <= SelectionStart Then
        If Not e Is Nothing Then
            e.Handled = True
            e = Nothing
        End If
        TextBox1.SelectionStart = SelectionStart
        TextBox1.SelectionLength = 0
        Me.SelectionCurrent = TextBox1.SelectionStart
    Else
        Me.SelectionCurrent = TextBox1.SelectionStart
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.Click
    CursorControl()
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_GotFocus(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.GotFocus

    CursorControl()
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyDown
    TextBox1.SelectionStart = Me.SelectionCurrent
    TextBox1.SelectionLength = 0
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Right Or e.KeyCode = Keys.Left Or e.KeyCode = Keys.Down Or e.KeyCode = Keys.Up Then
        e.Handled = True
        e = Nothing
    End If
    CursorControl(e)
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyPress
    TextBox1.SelectionStart = Me.SelectionCurrent
    TextBox1.SelectionLength = 0
    If e.KeyChar = "_" Then
        e.Handled = True

    End If
    If TextBox1.SelectionStart >= SelectionEnd Then
        e.Handled = True
        e = Nothing
    ElseIf TextBox1.SelectionStart <= SelectionStart Then
        e.Handled = True
        e = Nothing
    Else
        TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text.Substring(0, TextBox1.SelectionStart) & e.KeyChar & TextBox1.Text.Substring(TextBox1.SelectionStart + 1, TextBox1.Text.Length - TextBox1.SelectionStart - 1)
        TextBox1.SelectionStart = Me.SelectionCurrent
        e.Handled = True
        e = Nothing
    End If
    CursorControl()
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_KeyUp(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyUp
    TextBox1.SelectionStart = Me.SelectionCurrent
    TextBox1.SelectionLength = 0
    If e.KeyCode = 189 Then '_
        e.Handled = True
    End If
    Me.SelectionCurrent = Me.SelectionCurrent + 1
    Me.TextBox1.SelectionStart = Me.SelectionCurrent
    CursorControl(e)
End Sub
```

End Class

Answer (score 0):

Put three TextBoxes next to each other and allow only the middle one to be edited.  Here's some XAML:

```
<StackPanel
   Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBox
            Text="He share of"
            IsReadOnly=True />
        <TextBox
            Text="<Enter your phrase here>" />
        <TextBox
            Text="to worse. ......."
            IsReadOnly=True />
</StackPanel>
```

The end user will see the whole line as one unit.

Answer (score 0):

The Winform control [RichTextBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox(v=vs.110).aspx) via the [SelectionProtected Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.selectionprotected(v=vs.110).aspx) allows you to mark text ranges a readonly (protected).

Marking the entire text as protected and then selectively unprotecting the desired editable range will produce the desired effect.

```
Public Class Form1
    Private underlinedFont As Font

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        RichTextBox1.Text = "This is protected. This is unprotected."

        ' Protect all text
        RichTextBox1.SelectAll()
        RichTextBox1.SelectionProtected = True

        ' Unprotect the word "unprotected"
        Dim startUnProtected As Int32 = RichTextBox1.Find("unprotected", RichTextBoxFinds.WholeWord)
        If startUnProtected > -1 Then
            RichTextBox1.SelectionProtected = False
            If underlinedFont Is Nothing Then underlinedFont = New Font(RichTextBox1.Font.FontFamily, RichTextBox1.Font.Size, FontStyle.Underline, RichTextBox1.Font.Unit)
            RichTextBox1.SelectionFont = underlinedFont
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```